# Call QnA maker issue with postman

Tags: https, postman, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

I create a qna maler knowledge bases, and want to test it in postman.
But I got 415 error.(I had added content-type:application/json)
Here is the issue screenshot

1. QnA maker info

[image]

2. Postman issue

[image]

Can you guys tell me how to fix the issue

Comment: What do you have for the body? Is it selected as a raw data input?

Comment: @DannyDainton, Thank you.I fix it by choose raw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I choose `form-data` in postman.
After I select `raw`.
It works fine now!